# Cannot access value at 'user.email_activities'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, migration, rails-activerecord

I have `models/user.rb` that has association with `email_activities`:

```rb
class User
  .
  .
  has_many :email_activities
end
```

and `models/email_activity.rb`:

```rb
class EmailActivity
  .
  .
  belongs_to :user
end
```

I am accessing the `email_activities` for a particular `user`, in my controller like this:

```rb
user.email_activities
```

But this raises error:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid Exception: Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'email_activities.user_id' in 'where clause': SELECT `email_activities`.* FROM `email_activities` WHERE `email_activities`.`user_id` = 1
```

In `schema.rb`, `email_activities` table has no `user_id` key. To fix that, I generated a migration to add index like this:

```rb
def change
  add_index :email_activities, :user_id
end
```

But, running the migration, results in different error:

```
Mysql2::Error: Key column 'user_id' doesn't exist in table
```

Can you help me in finding what I am doing wrong?

Comment: need to add a user_id column to email_activities. usually do this adding a reference like so `add_reference :email_activities, :user, foreign_key: true, index: true`

Comment: @dbugger It works. BUT Other fields (user has many leads, lead belongs to the user) have the same associations and `add_index`, as I have defined above. And `user.leads` works! Why do I have to define `add_reference` when other fields are working fine with add_index (no add_reference needed). Is there any other way to add_reference?

Comment: I don't know. Because you created the proper columns for them before? All I know is if you want an association -- you need a column to hold it in.

Comment: Thanks, @dbugger. Anyways, add_index and add_reference are resulting in same column creation: `add_index` - `t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_leads_on_user_id", using: :btree` . And `add_reference` - `t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_email_activities_on_user_id", using: :btree` with foreign_key.

Comment: @AnasAnsari `add_index` and `add_reference` are not the same. [`add_index`](https://apidock.com/rails/v6.1.3.1/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements/add_index) adds an index. [`add_reference`](https://apidock.com/rails/v6.1.3.1/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements/add_reference) adds a column and an index.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to add a `user_id` field to the `email_activities` table, which makes sense.
However, with your migration you're adding an index to a field that doesn't exist (which is why you are getting that error).
You should instead be adding the field itself.

Use this migration instead:

```
def change
  add_column(:email_activities, :user_id, :integer, default: nil, null: false, after: :id)
end
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Please ref: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72190922/cannot-access-value-at-user-email-activities?noredirect=1#comment127550425_72190922

Comment: One way or the other, if you have a Model with a `belongs_to` relationship, then that model's DB table needs a field that points back to the owner's ID.
If you have other models with this type of relationship and they are working, it is because this DB field was added in a migration. Maybe you used Rails scaffolding generators to accomplish that, and now you're not using Rails scaffolding anymore. There could be other reasons, but that is my guess.